# Unity, VRChat SDK3, Udon Graph (bug?)

Tags: unity

I'm trying to create a VRChat world in Unity, using VRchat World SDK3.
But I'm getting a strange behavior in Udon Graph assets (as shown by the arrows in the screenshot).

Steps I took:

1. I've installed the appropriate Unity version (`2018-04-20f1`) via the hub,
2. Then proceeded to importing VRChat SDK 3 (`VRCSDK3-WORLD-2020.12.09.04.44_Public.unitypackage`),
3. Then on the project tab, I navigated to the "Udon" folder, created a subfolder and inside it I created a `Udon Graph Program Asset`.
4. Finally, I opened `Udon Graph` and I added a public `GameObject` variable.

The result was as seen in the image seen bellow: the `GameObject` variable displays a buggy text (the text `self (GameObject)` shows up twice, superimposed on top of itself - as indicated by the arrows in the attached screenshot).

[image: unity/vrchatsdk/udon bug?]

Comment: I don't think it's showing `self (GameObject)` twice; when I zoomed in, it looks more like `self (GameObject)` has been superimposed over `Name (GameObject)`

Comment: Thank you for that observation. I wonder why this is happening, I've re-installed unity, re-downloaded the sdk, downgraded unity, upgraded unity, reproduced the issue each time starting from a clean project. Im puzzled and stuck here.

Comment: I'm not steeped in the Unity scene, but to me it looks like a bug. I can't imagine why that would be an intended way for a UI to signal that you've done something wrong. If you're able to reproduce the problem (especially on another machine) & you don't see any mention of this in their knowledge base, I'd encourage you to [file a bug report](https://docs.vrchat.com/docs/what-is-udon) (support link at bottom of page).